# running shader code in emscripten

Tags: webgl, emscripten

I'm trying to convert a small game suing emscripten . I managed to compile it without any error but I've got the following error while trying to compile/use shaders
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid 
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked

this is the shader code

vertex:

```
attribute vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
attribute vec2 vertexUV;
varying vec2 UV;
varying float alfa;
uniform mat4 Proj;

void main()
{
    UV = vertexUV;
    alfa = vertexPosition_modelspace.z;
    gl_Position = Proj * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0);

}
```

fragment

```
varying vec2 UV;
varying float alfa;
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;

    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D( myTextureSampler, UV );
        gl_FragColor.a =gl_FragColor.a* alfa;
    }
```

Any help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing

```
precision mediump float;
```

at the top of your fragment shader. OpenGL ES 2.0 (and therefore WebGL) requires you specify precision in fragment shaders.

Ideally your original C/C++ program would have checked for errors and printed the errors out because the browser would probably have told you the issue. Optionally you could probably wrap `linkProgram` and `compileShader` something like

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
oldLinkProgram = gl.linkProgram;
gl.linkProgram = function() {

  // call the original linkProgram
  oldLinkProgram.apply(gl, arguments);

  var program = arguments[0];

  // Check the link status
  var linked = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (!linked) {
      console.error("ERROR !!!! linking program: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  }
};

oldCompileShader = gl.compileShader;
gl.compileShader = function() {

  // call the original compileShader
  oldCompileShader.apply(gl, arguments);

  var shader = arguments[0];

  // Check the compile status
  var compiled = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (!compiled) {
      console.error("ERROR !!!! compiling program: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  }
};
```

Then check your browser's console for errors.